# This mysql query returns 500 server error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can't figure this out.  This query inserts a new record with all the fields as needed but for whatever reason, it gives me a 500 server error after the insertion returning neither true or false:

```
$connection = Database::getConnection();
$query = "INSERT INTO reviews 
          VALUES ('0', (SELECT tbl_id FROM table WHERE brand = '$brand' AND model = '$model'), 
          (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user'), '$overall', '$lvalue', 
          '$pvalue', '$dvalue', '$vvalue', '$summary', 
          '$review', '$date')";
$result = $connection -> query($query);

   if (!$result || $result -> affected_rows < 1) {
      $result -> close();
      return FALSE;
   } else {
      $result -> close();
      return TRUE;
  }
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: One says: `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in /path/to/file on line 155` and another says `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE in /path/to/file on line 156`

Comment: How to view those logs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` contains a instance of `mysqli_result` which DOES NOT have a `close()` method.

If you want to close the connection, it should be

```
$connection->close();
```

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php